# Не работает ?limit=100 и offset в POST запросе

Tags: python, requests, moysklad-json-api

Почему лимит в ответе 25? Так же если я задаю в url offset - в ответе от сервера он не учтен.

```
url = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/counterparty/?limit=100'
CounterpartiesMeta = []

for c in range(0, len(filtered)): 
    CounterpartiesMeta.append({"counterparty": {"meta": filtered[c]}})

body = [{"counterparties": CounterpartiesMeta}]

r = requests.post(url, auth=auth, json=body)
response = json.loads(r.content)
response = json.dumps(response, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
print(response)
```

В ответ получаю такие метаданные

```
"meta": {
    "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/counterparty?limit=100",
    "type": "counterparty",
    "mediaType": "application/json",
    "size": 77,
    "limit": 25,
    "offset": 0,
    "nextHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/counterparty?limit=25&offset=0"
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текст должен быть текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: @Андрей, внесите **всю** информацию в вопрос текстом. Иначе вопрос долго не проживет - его забанят

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неверно используете параметр limit. Пример ниже

```
curl -X GET 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/counterparty?limit=100' -H 'Authorization: Basic <>='
```

Comment: Перевожу ваш ответ на питоничий :) `r = requests.get(url, auth=auth, json=body)`

Comment: С GET запросом работает, а с POST - нет. Вот страница [документации](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Какой смысл limit'а в POST, если вы явно передаете необходимое число контрагентов

Comment: Offset тоже не работает и я не могу получить информацию по всем 77 переданным контрагентам.

Comment: Прикрепите ваш запрос в формате CURL

Comment: `curl -i --user login:pass -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"counterparties": [{"counterparty": {"meta": "мета контрагента"}}, ...]}' https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/report/counterparty/?limit=100`

Comment: Во-первых, параметр limit не нужен в вашем запросе, во-вторых, / перед вопросительным знаком лишний

Comment: limit и offset не работают в всех post запросах?

Comment: Не работают в POST запросах, только в GET

Comment: ок, благодарю за информацию